# Want to create a Materialized View on commit from a View which is in another Database using a Database Link

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I am able to create a Materialized View(MV) **on demand** from another View which is in another database using database link. Now, the requirement is changed to show the commit changes immediately in the current view, so I want create a MV on commit, can I create a MV on commit using a view in another database with database link. If they is no way of creating it, then what aproach do I need to take for updating my MV on demand when the source view gets updated with new records.

Comment: You can't do an `on commit` refresh over a database link.  Can you create an on demand materialized view and refresh it frequently enough that it is "good enough" (i.e. every minute)?  If you're looking for something closer to real time, you'd be looking at moving to GoldenGate for streaming based replication which requires additional licensing costs (or using Streams if you're on an older version of Oracle and OK with using a feature that is desupported now).

Comment: Database link is a saved connection parameters in the local database. Remote database cannot know who is *going to* connect to it, so it has no ability to refresh remote MV `on commit`.

Comment: You could forget materialized views and have a regular view that queries the remote table over the link. Or you could setup a trigger on the remote table that updates a table in your local database to match insert/update/delete operations on the remote table. Both these actions would affect the remote database more than MVs but maybe refreshing every commit would be as bad.

Comment: You may add a reverse DB link and a trigger at the source side, that will call (or schedule) refresh at your DB side via reverse DB link. Or use fast refreshable materialized view and schedule refresh on small periods.